# What are the acceptable ways to say, "I have no idea."?

Tags: modismos

Are the following sentences acceptable was to say, "I have no idea":

> 1. No tengo idea.
> 2. No tengo ni idea.
> 3. No tengo nada de idea.

Are there any additional ways to express this?

Comment: "No tengo nada de idea" doesn't sound too natural to me (Spain).

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Yay. Las dos primeras suenan bien. La tercera no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Out of the three options you have, "No tengo ni idea" would be the most natural:

- No tengo ni idea de cómo resolver este problema.

A shortened version, "ni idea", can be used as well. But it's more frequently used as an answer.

- ¿Cuándo construyeron este monumento?
- Ni idea.

You can use also "No tengo la menor idea" (I don't have the slighest/faintest idea).

Answer (score 1):

"no tengo idea" es más natural para mí :-)

Answer (score 1):

Other way includes *y yo qué sé.*
To my ear, *no tengo idea* is the most used. Even the expression *no tengo ninguna idea* is widely used as a double negative to show emphasis. However, the expression *no tengo nada de idea* seems to have been taken from a translator, and this form is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to say "I have no idea" is "No tengo ni idea". Also, you can say only "ni idea", for example:

> -¿Sabes cómo se llama ese chico? (Do you know the name of that boy?)
>   -Ni idea. (No idea, that is "I have no idea")

The second one is most used in colloquial situations.

Answer (score 0):

My tendency would be to say

```
No tengo la menor idea.
```

Answer (score -2):

> Ni tengo una idea

sounds like it would work.

Comment: You should elaborate a little bit more why. I actually don't think it works. The meaning to me is closer to "Neither I have and idea" quite different from the original intent "I have no idea".

Comment: @Diego Well may be that's why he put *would work* instead of *will work.* But, this answer should've been more elaborated.